# Views - Edit, view, delete node in dropdown

Tags: views, navigation

In facebook, on every post, there is a little arrow in the corner with content about that post.

[image: I want this]

Is there a Drupal module which allows me to achieve this?

What I want to do is:

I have different content types which a user can add.  I want to add the 'edit node', 'delete node' and 'view node' link into a small dropdown which allows the user to choose any of these options by clicking on the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved through contextual links. You can add new links through a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089922) or with the [Custom Contextual Links](https://www.drupal.org/project/ccl) module (CCL).

Comment: Just to clarify, the Edit and Delete functions should be available just by turning on the core "Contextual Links" module. If you want to add other contextual options, you will need to do what Pierre recommends.

Comment: I use views to display the 'view-', 'edit-' and 'delete node' links.  What I want is to put those options in a dropdown, and activate the dropdown with an icon.  The icon should be in the top right corner.